# Inventory with parent and child

Tags: ansible

I have created inventory

```
[dev:children]

d2-dev

jms-dev

[d2-dev]

 host1

[jms-dev]

 host2


[test:children]

d2-test

jms-test

[d2-test]

host3

[jms-test]

host4


[stage:children]
```

...

I am passing variables with

`ansible-playbook  test.yml -i hosts --extra-vars '{"env":"dev"}'`

for dev/test/sgate.

In playbook I am checking

```
- name: Stop Service

  service:

    name: httpd

    state: stopped

  when: inventory_hostname in groups[d2-{{ env }}]
```

I am getting error
[WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: inventory_hostname  in
groups['d2-"{{env}}"']

My objective is to have one inventory and one playbook and call with extra variable and replace with env. How can I acheive this

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting error [WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: inventory_hostname in groups['d2-"{{env}}"']

It is correct for two reasons: as it stated about the mustaches, but also because even if it did what you asked, the expression would resolve to the string `'d2-"dev"'` which is very unlikely to be what you wanted

The correct fix for that is to set a task-local variable, in which you can use jinja templates as you wish, then use *that* variable in the `when:`:

```
- debug: msg="like this"
  when: inventory_hostname in groups[the_group]
  vars:
    the_group: d2-{{env}}
```

Comment: Thanks its worked, if I have 20/30 groups of diff application hosts, it will be messy to  define vars: for every group. Can I do array it is possible ?

Comment: I don't understand your question; do _what_ for every group? If you mean build a reverse index of host-to-groups mapping, then I think some crafty application of jinja filters will do that

Comment: i mean if i need webs,db,apps,infr groups, run checks I have to define every  with when: inventory_hostname in groups[the_group]
  vars:
    the_group: d2-{{env}} . I am trying to do                                                          vars:  the_group: - d2-{{env}} -http-{{dev}} ...            than cal the_group[1],[2]